# Form submission with redux-saga

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I have a react app. Firebase on the backend. Redux-saga for state management.
But my dispatch on form submit executes only once on initial render of UserForm comopnent.
I have a submit handler:

```
 const formSubmitHandler = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch({ type: 'REGISTER_USER', email, password });
  }
```

**I have my saga**

```
export function* registerUserHandler({email, password}) {
  try {
    const user = yield call(apiRequests.registerUser(email, password));
    yield put({ type: 'REG_USER', user })
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
} 

export function* registerNewWatcher() {
  yield takeLatest('REGISTER_USER', registerUserHandler);
}
```

This is giving me undefined for email and password. More correctly, cannot destructure from undefined.
What will I passto registerUserHandler in the watcher saga?

The error in this saga also causes other sagas in my rootSaga to fail.

**root saga**

```
export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([
    // fork(fetchUserHandler),
    fork(registerUserHandler)
  ]) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, I think u got the error because you are using the wrong syntax.

```
 const formSubmitHandler = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const params = { email, password }
    dispatch({ type: 'REGISTER_USER', params });
  }
```

Comment: No, still undefined for email and password.

Answer (score 0):

In case somone stumbles into this question it turns out it is the matter of how you pass arguments to the apiRequest function.
You will not say:

```
const user = yield call(apiRequests.registerUser(email, password));
```

It is not necessary to use the call effect, although it is possible as seen in solution 2.

**Solution 1**

```
const user = yield apiRequests.registerUser(email, password));
```

**Solution 2**

```
 const user = yield call(apiRequests.registerUser, email, password);
```